# Python Pandas: Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries that I wish to manipulate using Pandas. Say:

```
m = [{"topic": "A", "type": "InvalidA", "count": 1}, {"topic": "A", "type": "InvalidB", "count": 1}, {"topic": "A", "type": "InvalidA", "count": 1}, {"topic": "B", "type": "InvalidA", "count": 1}, {"topic": "B", "type": "InvalidA", "count": 1}, {"topic": "B", "type": "InvalidB", "count": 1}]
```

1) first create a dataframe using the constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(m)
```

2) Group by columns ['topic] and ['type'] and count

```
df_group = df.groupby(['topic', 'type']).count()
```

I end up with:

```
                    count
topic   type    
 A      InvalidA    2
        InvalidB    1
 B      InvalidA    2
        InvalidB    1
```

I want to now convert this to a nested dict:

```
{ "A" : {"InvalidA" : 2,
         "InvalidB" : 1},
  "B" : {"InvalidA" : 2,
         "InvalidB":  1}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get from `df_group` to a nested dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `unstack` + `to_dict`

```
df_group['count'].unstack(0).to_dict()
Out[446]: {'A': {'InvalidA': 2, 'InvalidB': 1}, 'B': {'InvalidA': 2, 'InvalidB': 1}}
```

And also slightly change you `groupby` to `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.type,df.topic).to_dict()
Out[449]: {'A': {'InvalidA': 2, 'InvalidB': 1}, 'B': {'InvalidA': 2, 'InvalidB': 1}}
```